# Merging Datasets in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a rather simplistic question.

> Is there any way to merge $n$ data sets in SAS where $n > 2$. I know how to merge 2 data sets.

Thanks

gowers

Answer (score 2):

You can merge multiple data sets using the same syntax as for just two:

```
data all;
 merge ds1 ds2 ds3 ...;
 by some_list_of_variables;
run;
```

If you have many data sets you want to merge, you may want to right a macro that lists them all.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the code @itzy provided, you can identify your data sets using an IN= option on the MERGE statement. This allows you only accept the matching you need. Also, you must have common variable names to use in your BY statement. You can include a RENAME= statement to create a common variable for use in your BY statement.

(Untested code)

```
data all;
 merge ds1(in=one rename=(ds1_id=id)) 
       ds2(in=two rename=(ds2_id=id))
       ds3(in=three rename=(ds3_id=id))
       ;
 by some_list_of_variables;
 if one and two and three ; /* Creates only matching records from all */ 
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have said that you want to "merge" datasets, note that the MERGE statement is not the only option. If your merging key has duplicates in more than 1 dataset, then using the MERGE statement will might give logically wrong results even though it would work without complaining. In that case, you can use PROC SQL - I also recall that PROC SQL can be more efficient from SAS 9.1 onwards.

Example -

```
proc sql;
select <fieldlist>
from data1 t1, data2 t2, data3 t3, data4 t4
where <join condition>;
quit;
```